# remove alias prefix from TypoORM queryBuilder resultset

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I am fetching mysql rows with this queryBuilder request:

[image]

it works, but every property of rows i receve receives prefix of the table,
for example, if `table = 'sometable'`,
then i will receive:

```
[{sometable_id:123}, {sometable_id:234}];
```

even if i remove the `table` param - the entity classname will be prepended, like

```
[{sometable_id:123}, {sometable_id:234}];
```

how can i receive rows without the prefix??

Answer (score 2):

```
const like = await con.manager
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select(["like.LID", "like.VideoId", "like.ForLikes"])
        .from(Like, "like")
        .where("like.Status = :Status", { Status: "Active" })
        .andWhere("LikesRemaining > 0")
        .orderBy("random()")
        .limit(Limit)
        .getMany();
```

use `getMany()` for same result as table name or `getOne()` for one result.